# Were Craig Bierko and Yvonne Zima cast due to their physical resemblance of one another?

Tags: casting, the-long-kiss-goodnight

In [*The Long Kiss Goodnight*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0116908/), Charly informs Timothy that her daughter, Caitlin, whom she has been raising for the past 8 years, is his biological child.

Charly begs Timothy to look into Caitlin's eyes to prove to him that she is his daughter:

> **Charly**:  Look at her eyes.
>
> **Timothy**:  Why would I want to do that?
>
> **Charly**:  Because they're yours.  That night with you, I got pregnant. The little girl is your daughter.
>
> **Timothy**:  Hi, princess.  You mind if I take a look at your fuckin' eyes?

Timothy looks into Caitlin's eyes and immediately realizes that she is, in fact, his daughter.

[Craig Bierko](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0081572/?ref_=tt_cl_t4) (the actor portraying Timothy) and [Yvonne Zima](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0956531/?ref_=tt_cl_t3) (the actress portraying Caitlin) bear a striking resemblance to one another (especially around the eyes).

Below are stills from the above-mentioned scene in which Timothy is looking into Caitlin's eyes:

[image: Caitlin]

[image: Timothy]

**Is there any evidence to suggest that these two actors were cast in this movie due to their resemblance to each other?**  I understand that when casting a child for a movie, they do want the child to bear somewhat of a resemblance to the actors portraying their parents. However, the way that this particular scene was filmed really *does* focus on their eyes and makes it seem as though they could be biologically related.  **What is the casting tendency when there is a scene like this in a movie?**

Comment: I think you're reading too much into a passing resemblance (that frankly I don't see).

Comment: @Paulie_D Well, you see it in the scene.  They actually make it a point to show the resemblance of the two.  Have you ever seen the movie?

Comment: Many times...and, as I said, I don't see it. Opinions may differ. :)

Comment: @Paulie_D You've seen it and don't see that resemblance?  Hmmmm...okay.  Opinions do differ, I guess :)

Comment: Gheez, I *always* wonder this every time I see that film. It's such an extreme resemblance that it's hard to not notice.