# Does Caitlin really have Timothy's eyes?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-long-kiss-goodnight

Towards the end of the great Shane Black action thriller The [Long Kiss Goodnight](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0116908/?ref_=nv_sr_1), the lead antagonist, Timothy, is threatening to freeze Samantha Caine (aka Charly Baltimore) and her daughter in a cold store. In an attempt to save the child, Samantha asks Timothy to "look into her eyes" and claims they are **his** eyes because he is the father.

The claim is plausible as Samantha, when she was the spy Charly, had infiltrated Timothy's terrorist gang and had slept with Timothy (as well as at least one other member).

But it is neither obvious that the eyes match (I've tried rewatching the scene and I really can't tell) and later Hennessy tells the girl she has her mother's eyes. Samantha may have been gambling in a desperate situation to try to save the girl so she may not have believed the claim.

So does Caitlin really have Timothy's eyes?

Comment: http://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/64289/were-craig-bierko-and-yvonne-zima-cast-due-to-their-physical-resemblance-of-one

Comment: @madmada I read that question which has no answers and which *assumes* the answer to my question. I don't make that assumption since I'm completely unclear that it is true.

Comment: Yes,that question assumes the answer but if it/you didn't, the question might be considered opinion based. Also there's a discussion about what you're asking in the comments and 2 users think there's a resemble and 1 don't.

Comment: It's a little unclear what kind of answer you *expect* here, though. Beyond the characters claiming her having one or the other's eyes, how is anyone to clarify that beyond subjective impression? Personally, I thought so much that she had Timothy's eyes that the other question about the casting being deliberate has been on my mind from the first time I saw the film. You on the other hand don't see the similarity, which is as good an opinion as anyone else's. But beyond her being actually the actor's daughter (which she isn't), I don't really see how a satisfying answer would look to you here.